# Does the existence of an RP-complete language imply P = RP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

(I'm not sure if this is research-level, but I couldn't find an answer to this question elsewhere)
The question of whether there exists an RP-complete language seems to be open, but I guess we *believe* that there exists one (because we believe that P = RP). In other words, P = RP implies that there exists an RP-complete language. Is the converse known to be true/false?

Comment: For example, if RP = NP, then RP also has a complete language.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps this should be posed differently : we know that syntactic complexity classes have complete languages (that we get for free from their definitions). Is it necessarily the case that if a class (like RP) has a complete language, then it's equal to some syntactic complexity class?

Comment: Well, if RP has a complete language $L$, then it equals the syntactic class of all languages polynomial-time reducible to $L$.